# Raising the failure level of a coq tactic

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, ltac

When implementing a complex tactic in Ltac, there are some Ltac commands or tactic invocation that I expect to fail and where that is expected (e.g. to terminate a `repeat`, or to cause backtracking). These failures are usually raised at failure level 0.

Failures raised at higher level “escape” the surrounding `try` or `repeat` block, and are useful to signal unexpected failures.

What I am missing is a way to run a tactic `tac` and treat its failure, even at level 0, to be at a higher level, while retaining the message of the failure. This would let me make sure that `repeat` does not terminate due to a Ltac programming error on my side.

Can I implement such a failure-raising-level higher-order tactic in Ltac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a tactic to achieve that in Ocaml. I put that on GitHub [here](https://github.com/lemonidas/raise_error_tactic).

For example the following should raise an error instead of silently succeeding:

```
repeat (match goal with 
          | [ |- _ ] => 
            raise_error_level (assert (3 = 3) by idtac)
        end).
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it is possible to get exactly what you want, but I sometimes use the following idiom:

```
tactic_expression_that_may_fail_with_level_0
|| fail 1000 "There was some problem here"
```

If the first tactic fails with level 0, the `||` will try to run the second one, which will fail with a very high level and report it to you.

It would help if you could provide a concrete use case to see if some other technique would be better suited.

Comment: Your work around does exactly what I want (and I used it so far), with the exception that I lose the actual information on the level-0 failure, which, for a few tactics, can actually be quite useful.